# SQL: User ban list from specific items

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of products:

```
ID, Name, Time, Creator, Owner, Size, Color, ...
```

I want to ban certain user from certain products. I thought of 2 solutions.

**1)** I create a table with info about Banned User:

```
Product ID, User ID, BannedOrNot
```

**2)** Add a column for every user to the product table.

```
ID, Name, Time, Creator, Owner, Size, Color, ..., User 1, User 2, User 3
```

There I add if user is banned from this product or not.

I know the 1 solution is better. But I have a really incredible amount of queries to deal with every second. So I want to avoid many queries because of performance.

The user does not select a specific product. The script does select the product automatically depending on things like `Size, Color` etc. But the problem is it does not know if the user is banned from this product or not.

First solution would require to first get all data from the banned list which belongs to the user who is accessing the product table. And then depending on if user is not banned select the entry from product table.

I am using PHP, MySQL if that matters.

Comment: DEFINITELY NOT 2!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THAT IS CRAZY... and you only need to store 'banned' user-products. So you don't need the `bannedornot` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the first solution. Add only a row for each banned user to the table, and add this to your products queries

In the FROM clause

```
LEFT JOIN banned_table ON (products.id = banned_table.producs_id 
                           AND banned_table.user_id = <current_user_id>)
```

In the WHERE clause

```
... AND banned_table.id IS NULL
```

This only retrieve one row of banned_table if exists and avoid the query results with banned products.

Hope it works fine for you.

Comment: So I have this query now. Is this correct? (I use PDO)


`SELECT id, name, time, creator, owner, size, color, active ... 
FROM products LEFT JOIN banned_table ON (products.id = banned_table.product_id AND banned_table.user_id = :user_id) 
WHERE banned_table.id IS NULL AND active = :active AND size < :size AND owner = :owner AND id != :id ....`

Comment: Yes, you only need to add the `JOIN` with two conditions and the `WHERE` one.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying. Also is this query good if I want the best performance possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's better than the other one. If the size of products table increases, it could be even worse to DB performance. I think that JOIN is optimal. Ensure to add index on your `banned_table` on both products_id and user_id, or even do a composed PK with them.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new table with a Foreign Key to products:

```
Banned(Product -> Products, User)
```

You can create it using this Queries:

```
CREATE TABLE banned(product NOT NULL, user NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (product) REFERENCES products(id))
```

You can then get the products for a single user with one Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products

MINUS  

SELECT p.Name, p.Time, p.Creator, ..
FROM PRODUCTS p LEFT JOIN BANNED b on (p.id = b.product)
WHERE b.user ='YOURUSER'
```

Comment: Nicolas Te, welcome to SO. Remember that a relational table should always have a PRIMARY KEY.